# How could I resolve this ERROR 1007 (HY000) mysql error

Tags: mysql

I come across a very weird problem and need your suggestions and help.
I run mysql from a docker container (percona 5.7). And I got below weird result:
So for now I'm unable to create the database nor drop it, how could I resolve this?

```
mysql> drop database digitalContent;
ERROR 1008 (HY000): Can't drop database 'digitalcontent'; database doesn't exist
mysql>  CREATE DATABASE  digitalContent;
ERROR 1007 (HY000): Can't create database 'digitalContent'; database exists
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| acl       |
| autobuilder                |
| automaker      |
| base            |
| binary            |
| cards              |
| decimals             |
| fho            |
| logs               |
| matrix             |
| matrix_with_tags   |
| maxmind            |
| memories           |
| messaging          |
| monsters        |
| mysql              |
| ppl_rank           |
| performance_schema |
| ppoints        |
| pros         |
| ps                 |
| users              |
| who          |
+--------------------+
24 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I would like to create the database of "digitalContent", and know the reason why above doesn't work

Comment: This could be due to cahe, Can you restart your mysql service, and try again